# Is there any way to plot a calibration curve and calculate a Brier score from a XGBoost model in R?

Tags: r, xgboost, auc, calibration

I have trained a XGBoost model in R, tuned the hyperparameters and plotted the ROC curve.

Is there any easy way to plot a calibration curve and calculate Brier score, calibration intercept and calibration slope? I can't seem to find anyway to do this in R.

```
# Train the XGBoost model for predicting 'Variable'
xgb_model <- train(
  `Variable` ~ X + Y + Z,
  data = train_data,
  method = "xgbTree",
  trControl = ctrl,
  tuneGrid = xgb_grid,
  verbose = TRUE)


# Make predictions on the test set
predictions <- predict(xgb_model, newdata = test_data)

# Convert 'Patient Allocation' in the test dataset to a factor
test_data$`Variable` <- factor(test_data$`Variable`, levels = levels(predictions))

# Compute the confusion matrix
confusionMatrix(predictions, test_data$`Variable`)

# Compute class probabilities on the test set
probs <- predict(xgb_model, newdata = test_data, type = "prob")

# Compute AUC-ROC
roc_obj <- roc(test_data$`Variable`, probs[,2])  # Compute ROC curve
```

Thank you,

I tried searching for ways to plot the calibration curve on stack overflow and could not find any.

Comment: Wouldn't a calibration curve just be a regression line of "Variable" vs predicted?

Comment: Yes from my understanding, but I know there are packages in Python for example that will automatically create the calibration curve and calculate values like Brier score, calibration intercept, and calibration slope.

Comment: Package rec requests are off-topic here. Why not do a Google search?